# float value showing a fixed value

Tags: c

When I store a float value of 12 decimal places after upto 6 decimals places it is showing fixed value.If it is garbage value then it should be different for different compilers but when i saw the output in my book and tried it practically they both are same results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 1.234567890000;

    printf("%.12f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.234567880630   // In my book it also represents same output.
```

Comment: What is your question?  Why your output doesn't match your input?  Because you're giving the input as base 10, but the computer is storing it as base two, and there's not enough resolution in a `float` to get all twelve decimal places accurately.

Comment: Note that you start with a `double` literal, convert it to `float` for storage, and then convert it back to `double` for printing.

Answer (score 3):

> If it is garbage value then it should be different for different compilers but when i saw the output in my book and tried it practically they both are same results.

There is a very good chance that your compiler and the book you are using both use the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) standards for floating point numbers, and have similar mechansims for handling the values.  As such, they'll probably get the same answer, as will many other compilers and systems.

The main issue is in [how floating point values are stored](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/) and function.  There isn't enough precision in a 32 bit float value to represent your 12 decimal places exactly, so you get a different output than what you entered.

Answer (score 1):

Expect compilers to implement the IEEE  754 Standard for floating point numbers. For float ( binary32 bits) there are 23 bits for the digits and 1 for the sign. This gives you 7.x decimal digits.  So what you see is correct.

If you need more precision use double which uses 52 bits for the digit and gives you 34 digits precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using floating point, you might also find this an enlightening article, saving you from many surprises: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Remember that, unlike in math, 10 times 0.1 is hardly ever 1.

Answer (score 0):

A float (on most systems) stores it's value in 32 bits, with those bits divided between sign, exponent and "Significand" (the main part of the value) this gives between 7 and 8 digits of decimal precision for most values, well short of the 12 digits you are looking at.

a double uses 64 bits and gives 15-16 digits of precision for most values.

You are getting odd values around the 7-9th digit because your compiler has to round the value to store it. Rounding methods are pretty much standard, so compilers will generally give the same rounded results.

Please note that C/C++ generally requires compilers to provide "minimal" sizes, however the values may be stored in larger storage, for instance in CPU Registers, so your milege will vary on low significance bits.